# Spring Redirecting from Http to Https Breaks Rest Controller Test

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm redirecting from http to https using the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory instructions found here:

http://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/

However this breaks the testing of the rest controller, even though it uses an Application to run the test that does not contain or reference the TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory configuration performing the redirection.

If I remove the redirection configuration from the Application that contains the @SpringBootApplication annotation that runs the application, the test passes.

Any idea how to keep the production configuration for the application in place without breaking the Rest controller configuration?

TIA,
- Ole

Comment: You are going to have to give some more information. You say you have a different Application.java (@SpringBootApplication) specific for your testing? Why and what does it contain then?

How does it "break" your test? What is going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use the **TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory** in your **Application.java** in your test, you could always add work with [Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) to make sure that bean is only loaded when you start your application with a certain profile (production for example).

Then the **@Bean** **TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory** would have a **@Profile("production")** annotation, and your test would not create that bean unless you are using the production profile explicitly.

I will update this answer when you give more information regarding your problem.

Comment: Driss - Brilliant!  I just added @Profile("production") to the production configuration class, and now it is excluded from scanning during unit testing.  That was exactly what I needed.  Almost too simple :).  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1684269 if this was the solution to your problem, you can mark this answer as accepted. :)